# Refresh iTunes metadata on songs purchased from the iTunes store

Tags: itunes, metadata

I have a bunch of single songs from the iTunes store (Starbucks Pick of the Week) and in a misguided attempt to get them to organize them the way I wanted, I screwed up much of the metadata for these songs.

Is there a way to get it back, like you can with songs you directly imported from a CD using  "Get Track Names"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For songs you purchased, check to see if iTunes in the cloud allows you to download again the songs from the store.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519 - Downloading past purchases
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5085 - iTunes in the cloud availability per country

If so, delete all the incorrect purchased tracks (making a backup of the computer just in case) and then re-download the affected tracks.